# JPanel only loads after Minimizing and then Maximizing frame.

Tags: java, html, panel, show, minimize

If I run my application, I have to minimize and maximize it again to see anything. I suppose it is caused by using HTML code in my Label... Any idea how to solve this? If yes, how can I solve it?

```
lblUitleg.setText("<html>QuizIT is een vragenreeks over Informaticabeeher. Er worden in totaal 6 vragen gesteld.<br> Om geslaagd te zijn, moet je 4/6 behalen. Succes!</html>");
```

I used HTML to make a newline in my label.

In the end, it should look like this... http://prntscr.com/5r55le

```
package quiz;

// Imp.
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Quiz {

    // Decl. Frame
    public static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creat. Frame
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(600,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("QuizIT | Knowledge is Power...");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(new Paneel());

    }

    public static class Paneel extends JPanel {

        // Decl. Var.
        public JPanel pnlWelkom, pnlUitleg, pnlVragen, pnlVraag1, pnlVraag2, pnlVraag3, pnlVraag4, pnlVraag5, pnlVraag6, pnlPunten;
        public JLabel lblNaam, lblWelkom, lblUitleg, lblVraag1, lblVraag2, lblVraag3, lblVraag4, lblVraag5, lblVraag6;
        public JButton btnStart, btnVraag1, btnVraag2, btnVraag3, btnVraag4, btnVraag5, btnVraag6;

        public Paneel() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            // Init. Var.
            pnlWelkom = new JPanel();
            pnlUitleg = new JPanel();
            pnlVraag1 = new JPanel();
            pnlVraag2 = new JPanel();
            pnlVraag3 = new JPanel();
            pnlVraag4 = new JPanel();
            pnlVraag5 = new JPanel();
            pnlVraag6 = new JPanel();
            pnlPunten = new JPanel();
            pnlVragen = new JPanel();

            lblUitleg = new JLabel();
            lblUitleg.setText("<html>QuizIT is een vragenreeks over Informaticabeeher. Er worden in totaal 6 vragen gesteld.<br> Om geslaagd te zijn, moet je 4/6 behalen. Succes!</html>");

            btnStart = new JButton("Start de Quiz!");

            // BackGround Color
            pnlWelkom.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            pnlUitleg.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            pnlPunten.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            // Components -> Panels
            pnlUitleg.add(lblUitleg);
            pnlWelkom.add(btnStart);

            // Local. Panels
            add(pnlUitleg, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(pnlWelkom, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(pnlPunten, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add frame.pack(); to your code like this :

```
frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(600,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("QuizIT | Knowledge is Power...");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.setContentPane(new Paneel());
        frame.pack();   // NOTE HERE!
```

Comment: @BenjiNaesen: if an answer answers the question, it is customary to mark it as 'the answer', which you have done.  If an answer helps, it is also customary to upvote it.

Comment: I beg your pardon, didn't check the reputation requirement.  My mistake.

Comment: Np. Did it now as I reached my 15. @arcy